# SELECT query for multiple columns with multiple variables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm getting JSON from the client side and want to check if the received item exists in the database. So i'm excuting a query that matches all columns except for the ID.

I've tried two queries and none of them worked. The first one:

```
item = db.execute("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE (product, origin, amount, image, best_before_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(newProduct['product'], newProduct['origin'], newProduct['amount'], newProduct['image'], newProduct['best_before_date'])).fetchone()
```

this one is giving a syntax error which says:

```
OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

And the second is:

```
item = db.execute("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE product=?", (newProduct['product']), " AND origin=?", (newProduct['origin']), " AND amount=?", (newProduct['amount']), " AND image=?", (newProduct['image']), "AND best_before_date=?", (newProduct['best_before_date'])).fetchone()
```

Which is giving the following error:

```
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (10 given)
```

I couldn't figure out where the syntax error exactly is, nor could I find any other way to excute this query.

The full piece of code:

```
@post('/add')
def add(db):

newProduct = request.json

item = db.execute("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE (product, origin, amount, image, best_before_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(newProduct['product'], newProduct['origin'], newProduct['amount'], newProduct['image'], newProduct['best_before_date'])).fetchone()
```

Comment: I did read the tutorial from W3 schools and some other resources. I don't know what makes you judge that I didn't try!

Comment: @RiggsFolly -> perhaps there is a more constructive way to formulate your commentary?

Comment: Isn't this my question in the first place? That i've been trying different ways and getting errors... etc that I eventually decided to ask for help! Isn't this what this website is for? SQL is not my field and I'm a novice who couldn't figure this out. I still don't see where the problem is in my question

Comment: @Alexwatson - it looks like you might have a few issues going on here. Have you tried running the query in the SQL Workbench first, to narrow down any errors? As it stands, there's too much going on here for this to be a good question. I would recommend narrowing down to one issue at a time, then asking on that - you'll get better results.

Comment: @theMayer Yea probably. But honestly, an I wrong in my statement

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, you are. This is a place for people to ask questions. If you think the question should be improved, you should comment to that effect.

Comment: @Alexwatson -> aside from the specific errors, what do you mean by "check if the received item exists in the database?" Typically, you would evaluate based on a single key value to determine whether something exists already, so I'm a bit confused as to the end goal.

Comment: [SELECT Statement symtax](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/select.php)

Comment: @theMayer The client adds products to the database by submitting a form. So I want to check if the product with the exact same details already exists in the database, to prevent duplication. The client doesn't submit the id of the product as it's autogenerated, so I can't use that column to check if that product exists. Hope it's clear

Comment: No @theMayer.. Typically you would add a Unique key on a column to prevent duplicates. Selecting the record first to check if it already exists you could get race conditions.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, but he mentioned JSON, so I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this isn't a direct answer *per se*, but rather some guidance on general SQL approach and troubleshooting which may help you get to the root of the issue.

First, its rarely a good idea to run raw SQL statements directly from code. Instead, it's a better idea to set up a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) to execute the specific code you wish to run. The advantage here is that you separate issues using the Python client with issues involving your data query itself. By creating a sp, you'll also be validating the syntax of the command itself.

Second, once you get the stored procedure syntax correct, you can begin troubleshooting on the python code itself. I think you'll find that it is much easier to work with the SQL command object than trying to do it the way you are. [This tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-python/) may be a good starting point.

Third, to ensure duplicates do not get inserted into a database, you create unique indexes. The correct way to achieve the goal here would be to attempt the insert, and the insert would fail if there is a duplicate. [Here is a resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/create-index.php) which might help with that.

**Proper syntax for insert command**

```
insert into supermarket (product, origin, amount, image, best_before_date)
values (@product, @origin, @amount, @image, @best_before_date)
```

**Proper syntax to create index**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_supermarket
  using HASH
ON supermarket (product, origin, amount, image, best_before_date)
```